# Could not convert depth image to laserscan: scan_height ( 1 pixels) is too large for the image height

Tags: realsense, depth-image, depthimage-to-laserscan

**Camera : IntelRealsense 435D**

**Computing device : Raspberrypi**

I'm trying to convert depthimage_to_laserscan ,while doing so the terminal shows an error message ->"Could not convert depth image to laserscan: scan_height ( 1 pixels) is too large for the image height".
I'm stuck i dont know how to proceed further.I dont know what specifics you people want so that you could debug my problem.So please ask me if any details needed.

My camera parameters are as such :

```
camera_info = CameraInfo()
camera_info.header.frame_id="mod_depth_frame"
camera_info.width = 640  
camera_info.height = 480 
camera_info.distortion_model = 'plumb_bob'
camera_info.K = [381.243, 0.0, 321.739, 0.0, 381.243, 321.739, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
camera_info.P = [381.243, 0.0, 320, 0.0, 0.0, 381.243, 241.478, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

***Note : before sending the depth image for conversion i'm cropping the depth image, that is, i only send the portion of  depth image in which object has been detected.So in that case the size of the depth image is always dynamic.***

Comment: it is fixed now.Cropping of the image was creating the problem.